# nodejs convert from import to require

Tags: node.js, npm, import, module, npm-request

I'm getting into a case not covered in [How to bulk convert some javascript code from import to require?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43353500/).

Here is the [original code from npm package `hot-import`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-import):

```
import * as assert  from 'assert'
import * as fs      from 'fs'
import * as path    from 'path'

import hotImport  from 'hot-import'
```

I converted them to,

```
const assert = require('assert')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const hotImport = require('hot-import')
const hotMod = await hotImport(MODULE_FILE)
```

but got:

```
TypeError: hotImport is not a function
```

After some massive trial-and-errors, I found that `const { hotImport } = require('hot-import')` works, but I have no idea why.

Can somebody summarize, when to use `const hotImport = require('hot-import')` and when to use `const { hotImport } = require('hot-import')` please?

And also related, why the demo code use,

```
import * as fs      from 'fs'
```

instead of

```
import fs      from 'fs'
```

? what's the differences between the two, and when to choose which?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose in fs package there are 5 exports available in fs package as following

```
export const readFile = _readFile;
export const appendFile = _appendFile;
export const writeFile = _writeFile;
export const open = _open;
export default fs; // fs class
```

Now,

**1.**

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

is asking to import all the named export from 'fs' in a local variable named fs. First 4 in above snippets are named exports. so now you can use them as  `fs.open('/home/demo.txt')` or `fs.writeFile('/home/demo.txt',...)`

**2.**

```
import { open } from 'fs'
```

is asking to import name export 'open' from fs into a local variable named open.
so now you can use it as `open('/home/demo.txt')`

**3.**

```
import fs from 'fs'
```

is asking to import the default export of the 'fs' module in the local `fs` variable that is the `fs` class in our example.

So when you are doing `const hotImport = require('hot-import')` then it is importing the default export from 'hot-import'. So you cannot directly use it as `hotImport(MODULE_FILE)`, instead you can use `hotImport.hotImport(MODULE_FILE)`.

You can read more about [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
const person = {
  first: 'Ridham',
  last: 'Tarpara',
  country: 'India',
  city: 'Ahmedabad',
  twitter: '@ridhamtarpara'
};
```

If you have person object then following two code will be the same

```
const first = person.first; // Ridham
const last = person.last;   // Tarpara

const { first, last } = person; // first = Ridham, last = Tarpara
```