# SyntaxError: "Cannot use import statement outside a module" - JavaScript in Python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, ethereum

## Problem Statement

I am trying to run a JavaScript code inside Python using [stpyv8](https://github.com/cloudflare/stpyv8). However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances_stpyv8/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    output = ctxt.eval("""
SyntaxError: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (  @ 3 : 0 )  -> import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
```

I do have a `package.json` file and my hunch is that the Python code isn't considering the json file because the error above is actually solved by the `package.json` file
[Fixing module error in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import):

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@uniswap/sdk": "^3.0.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2"
  }
}
```

I do have package.json

The JavaScript does run and outputs the following:

Here is the JavaScript file:

[image: js output]

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import * as fs from 'fs';

    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('Erc20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

let NFT = fs.readFileSync('UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ALCHEMY_API_ID)

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";

async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}


const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));
const MIN_TICK = -887272;
const MAX_TICK = 887272;

function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}

async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow).toFixed(18);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh).toFixed(18);
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    let sqrtPrice = sqrtPriceX96 / Q96;
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtPrice)/(sqrtPrice*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtPrice-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = (amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal)).toFixed(token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = (amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal)).toFixed(token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}

async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}

start(273381)
// Also it can be used without the position data if you pull the data it will work for any range
getTokenAmounts(12558033400096537032, 20259533801624375790673555415)
```

Python3 code:

```
import STPyV8

with STPyV8.JSContext() as ctxt:
  output = ctxt.eval("""

import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import * as fs from 'fs';

    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('Erc20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

let NFT = fs.readFileSync('UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/fRrLGBzCur7V6wCQjGRPdtmTUQzjCk2F")

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = "0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984";
const NFTmanager = "0xC36442b4a4522E871399CD717aBDD847Ab11FE88";

async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}


const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));
const MIN_TICK = -887272;
const MAX_TICK = 887272;

function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}

async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow).toFixed(18);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh).toFixed(18);
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    let sqrtPrice = sqrtPriceX96 / Q96;
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtPrice)/(sqrtPrice*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtPrice-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = (amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal)).toFixed(token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = (amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal)).toFixed(token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}

async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}

start(273381)
// Also it can be used without the position data if you pull the data it will work for any range
getTokenAmounts(12558033400096537032, 20259533801624375790673555415)
  """
  )

output = ctxt.eval()
print(output())
```

Again going back to my hunch, is it possible that Python isn't able to recognize the `package.json` in my project folder?

Comment: I get that this may be an interesting problem in its own right, but in terms of a practical solution create a self-contained JS bundle with webpack or rollup and call it a day.

Comment: Thanks @JaredSmith. I am not sure what is meant by "self-contained JS bundle with webpack or rollup and call it a day." Do you have some resources I can read?

I am not set on my solution and am open to any solution. I just need to get the output from JS into Python somehow.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/. It's a CLI program that takes a JS application, resolves all the dependencies, and concatenates it into a single self-contained source file, much like a native code compiler can produce a statically linked binary executable. It's frequently used in JS-land because a given client-side JS app will have hundreds of dependencies, you don't typically want a browser making hundreds of HTTP requests.

Comment: I dont think this is possible, i.e. you cannot use `require` or `import` with your library based on pyv8. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9850251/258174

Answer (score 2):

```
SyntaxError: "Cannot use import statement outside a module"
```

this error is clear, you are using `import` statement in the wrong place. for example, create a `test.js` file and add only this line of code

```
 import fs from "fs";
```

then execute the file with `node test.js`. you will get this error.

[image]

Because when you execute the file with `node` command it is `node.js` environment where it supports `commonjs` not `es6 modules`.

one solution is to change the file extension from `js` to `mjs`. if you change the `test.js` to `test.mjs` and run `node test.mjs` your code will execute successfully.

Second solution is instead of `import` use this syntax.

```
 const ethers = require('ethers');
```

Third solution is add this to `package.json` file

```
 "type": "module"
```

Comment: I have tried the require route, but it complains that "ethers" is not defined. I believe you do need the import function here. (Please see my comment to the below answer).

Comment: all solution does not work to me

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do what is described in [nodejs-convert-from-import-to-require](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124250/nodejs-convert-from-import-to-require)

so change :

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

to

```
const { JSBI } = require ("@uniswap/sdk")
const { ethers } = require ('ethers')
const fs = require('fs')
```

Comment: But now I am getting a `required not defined` error:
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobby/uni_balances_stpyv8/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    output = ctxt.eval("""
ReferenceError: ReferenceError: require is not defined (  @ 3 : 17 )  -> const { JSBI } = require ("@uniswap/sdk")
`