# JavaScript - how can i import frappe chart correctly without using link?

Tags: javascript, html, frappe, frappe-charts

I want to import frappe by using the following code

```
import { Chart } from "frappe-charts/dist/frappe-charts.min.esm";
```

I already downloaded frappe-charts package and put it into my project package.

But it always shows: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Now I just solved this problem but a new problem appeared.

The problems are:

1. index.html:1 Access to script at 'file:///Users/dizitong/Downloads/2yp7jv/js/index.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.
2. index.html:7 GET file:///Users/dizitong/Downloads/2yp7jv/js/index.js net::ERR_FAILED

Here is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Data Chart</title>
    <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <form id="municipality-form">
      <input type="text" id="input-area" placeholder="Type municipality name" />
      <button type="button" id="submit-data">Fetch Data</button>
</form>
```

And in my index.js

```
import { Chart } from "frappe-charts/dist/frappe-charts.min.esm";
```

Comment: Do any of these help? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384179/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62488898/node-js-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74500818/syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-javascript-in-pyth)

Comment: Please show us more context. Also, revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

If you use node.js set `"type": "module"` in package.json for use `import { Chart } from "frappe-charts";`, or set `<script type="module" src="your-file.js"></script>` in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script type="module" src="./five.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Hello World</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

```
// five.js
import { Chart } from 'https://unpkg.com/frappe-charts@latest/dist/frappe-charts.esm.js';
```

```
//package.json
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module", //set this
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of ECMAScript modules in HTML does not support the `file://` protocol.

1. If a web page is loaded from the net it generally can't access files on the client device, using the file protocol, because such access is blocked to prevent web pages accessing the file system on front-end devices.
2. If a page is loaded from local storage, attempts to implicitly load a module from local storage, by executing an import statement with a file URL as the [module-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#syntax) in the from clause, are blocked by CORS because it doesn't support `file://` URLs. The "Reason: CORS request not HTTP" text in error messages (issued by Firefox) is explained further on  [MDM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp).

The second reason accounts for both errors in the post: importing from file URLs *is not implemented* in HTML for reason of requiring a net based URL as the `module-name` in [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements.